# upvoted questions but with time-frames

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is more of a query. I do know that one can use for e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes to see the highest voted questions ever, but I'm more interested to know what kind of interesting questions were asked say within the last week or two and if votes were 5 or more. I am sure there is a way to do it, just don't know, looking forward to knowing. And if it's not, maybe as a feature-request.

Many a time I do come across some intriguing questions but due to lack of time or something else, I forget the whole thing and don't even remember the context of what was the appealing question. And the questions are usually unique, something that I had not thought about in one way or other.

Comment: There's https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like:

> interesting questions were asked say within the last week or two and if votes were 5 or more.

.. I would use these [search criteria](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is%3Aq+score%3A5..+created%3A14d..):

```
Is:q score:5.. created:14d..
```

Meaning:

- it's a question
- is scored 5 or higher
- was created less than 15 days ago

I often refer to the [search help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching) that's linked from the advanced search tips within the search function.

For:

> I do come across some intriguing questions but due to lack of time or something else, I forget the whole thing

I would recommend [bookmarking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-question-bookmarks-work) the question or [following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) it so that it's easier to find again later. Of course, you could also use your browser's bookmark feature.

Comment: true, the issue is at times I completely forget and close the session and the interesting question was the one below or the one above which I hadn't opened in a new tab. And because it is always in flow, once that question goes down or whatever, the chances of finding it again are slim to none.